# Study of sequences and series

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_i$ and $b_i$ such as $a_ib_i=a_i+b_i$. Let
$$a_i^{-1}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}-b_i^{-1}=a_{i,1}$$
And let
$$b_{i,1}=\frac{a_{i,1}}{a_{i,1}-1}$$
And, as $(a_{i,j-1}-1)(b_{i,j-1}-1)=1$
$$a_{i,j}=a_{i,j-1}^{-1}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}-b_{i,j-1}^{-1}$$
$$b_{i,j}=\frac{a_{i,j}}{a_{i,j}-1}$$
Question : We have 
$$\lim_{i\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(a_i)}=1;\quad{\lim_{i\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(b_i)}=\infty}$$
What are the expressions of $a_{i,j}$ in function of $a_i$ and $j$ and what are the limits, if they exist 
$$\lim_{i,j\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(a_{i,j})}$$
And
$$\lim_{i,j\longrightarrow{\infty}}{(b_{i,j})}$$
Can we conclude that, necessarily, $a_i=b_i=2$ (as, in that case $a_{i,1}=0=b_{i,1}$) ? Thank you !

Comment: Can you clarify if these are sequences or matrices or what ($a_i$ and $a_{i,j}$ is confusing to me).

Comment: They are rational sequences !